# Copying array variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Please could someone tell me why this operation changes the value of the original array?

```
var today = new Date(); 
var max_x_domain = [today];

var one_year_after_end = max_x_domain.slice(0)[0];
one_year_after_end.setYear(one_year_after_end.getFullYear() - 1);

console.log('array after operation', max_x_domain);
```

And how can I make a copy of `max_x_domain[1]`... do I need to use a clone method [as described here](http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165)?

This is... a surprising feature of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dateToCopy = new Date();

var newDate = new Date(dateToCopy);
```

**Refactored code**

```
var today = new Date(); 
var max_x_domain = [today];

var one_year_after_end = new Date(max_x_domain.slice(0)[0]);
one_year_after_end.setYear(one_year_after_end.getFullYear() - 1);

console.log('array after operation', max_x_domain);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not at all surprising if you consider that your array contains object references. As this section of the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) states:

> For object references (and not the actual object), `slice` copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object. If a referenced object changes, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays.

Answer (score 1):

when using `slice`you create a copy and therefor a new array, without modifying the original. But the Elements inside are not copied/cloned, unless they are of a primitive type (bool, string, number). Since you have a Date Object in there, there will be a new array created but the same reference to your date object will be 'copied'. Thus, if you want to have an fresh Date Object, do `new Date(oldDate)` / `var one_year_after_end=new Date(max_x_domain.slice(0)[0])` and you can modify it from there on without modifying the original Date Object.